# Css background-image doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, dreamweaver

I'm trying to make a website with Dreamweaver and Visual Studio.
The problem is when I use background or backgrouand-image in CSS, the image doesn't appear.

Here is the code:

CSS
/*Showcase*/

```
.showcase{
    min-height: 400px;
    background-image:url("../Take2/assets/bg.jpg") no-repeat -400px;
    text-align: center;
    color: aqua;
}
```

Html:

```
<section class="showcase">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <h1>Rent a <span>Ring Roamer</span></h1>
<p>Tired of the same old photo booth?<br>
 Let our Ring Roamer, Roamer attendant come to you on the Dance Floor or at their tables!<br>
Our Ring Roamer will capture photos of your guests, photos get shared via social media.<br>
The Ring Roamer is awesome because it is on the GO!<br>
The Ring Roamer Selfie Booth has many fun features including Boomerang videos, animated GIFs, and virtual filters.<br>
Your guests will be able to share their experience instantly.</p>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is because you are using `no-repeat -400px`

When you remove the no-repeat part, the image will successfully appear.

Like this: `background-image: url("../Take2/assets/bg.jpg")`

Hope it helps.